# Bash script to open, read, and write then save

Tags: bash

I'm new on this bash script thing. Can you show me some example on writing Bash script. I want to write a script that can read from a filename and save it to a variable; increment the value of the variable and write that variable back to the file and save it. This is what I have started and stuck on it so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
# if file exist

#echo "Testing \ "$1""
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
 echo "$1 does exist"
else
 echo "$1 does not exist!" 
 echo "Creating $1"
 touch $1

 echo "This is test" > $1
 exit 1
fi

#echo "Testing \ "$2""
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
 echo "Enter the filename"
elif [ -f "$2" ]; then
 echo "$2 Fille does exist" 
else
 echo "$2 File doesn't exist"
 echo "Creating $2"
 touch $2
exit 1
fi

counter=1
echo -n "Enter a file name : "
read file

if  [ ! -f $file ]
then
    echo "$file not a file!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Based on your code "so far" I have no idea what you're trying to do.  It looks like you're running the script with two filenames on the command line (`$1` and `$2`) then asking for a third filename in the script `read file`... which file are you trying to read/increment/write?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your script with some modifications.

```
#!/bin/bash
# if file exist

#echo "Testing \ "$1""
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
    read -r -p "Enter the filename" file1
else
    file1=$1
fi

if [ -f "$file1" ]
then
    echo "$file1 does exist"
else
     echo "$file1 does not exist!" 
     echo "Creating $file1"
     echo "1" > "$file1"
     exit 1
fi

#echo "Testing \ "$2""
if [ "$2" == "" ]
then
    read -r -p "Enter the filename" file2
else
    file1=$2
fi

if [ -f "$file2" ]
then
    echo "$file2 does exist"
else
     echo "$file2 does not exist!" 
     echo "Creating $file2"
     echo "1" > "$file2"
     exit 1
fi

if [ "$3" == "" ]
then
    read -r -p "Enter the filename" file3
else
    file3=$3
fi

# the following assumes that the data from the file is an integer
# and that it consists of only one line containing one value
# similar techniques can be used to do something much more powerful
data1=$(<"$file1")
data2=$(<"$file2")
# it's usually a good idea to validate data, but I have not included any validation
((data3 = data1 + data2))
echo "$data3" > "$file3"    # overwrite the previous contents of the file with the new value
```

As long as neither file1 or file2 changes, the contents of file3 will always be the same on repeated runnings of the script above. If file1 or file2 don't exist, a "1" is written to them as a default value.

Here is an improved version of the script using functions:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkarg () {
    local filename=$1
    if [ "$filename" == "" ]
    then
        read -r -p "Enter the filename" filename
    fi
    echo "$filename"
}

checkfile () {
    local filename=$1
    if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
        echo "$filename does exist"
    else
         echo "$filename does not exist!" 
         echo "Creating $filename"
         echo "1" > "$filename"
         # you could remove this exit if you want the script to continue
         # with newly created files instead of exiting
         exit 1
    fi
}

file1=$(checkarg "$1")
checkfile "$file1"

file2=$(checkarg "$2")
checkfile "$file2"

file3=$(checkarg "$3")

data1=$(< "$file1")
data2=$(< "$file2")
((data3 = data1 + data2))
echo "$data3" > "$file3"
```

Comment: i want to thank your first for your help...i'm trying to read from $1 and increment from $2 and write it to a destination which is $3 and save it. i think my script is bad. i didn't get it to do what i want it to....i don't know if this is possible..can you help...thank you again..

Comment: A system administrator is the only one who is likely to use ksh for anything serious - not to mention counting within a file. This question is relevant.

Comment: @David: The OP is using Bash. There are others who use Bash and ksh for serious purposes all the time. Developers are one example. I have removed my objection from my answer in any case.

Comment: @Alex: See my edited answer which hopefully fulfills that requirement.

Comment: Dennis..sorry for a late reply. thank Dennis and all of you guys. your comment has a great help for me.....

Comment: @Alex Vo: If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted.